# I'm trying to add Matplotlib to python 3.7 but I get this error message as show in the picture attached. Does anyone know a solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

I'm trying to add Matplotlib to python 3.7 but I get this error message as show in the picture attached. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Are you using a fairly barebones python installation? What OS are you on? Could you try installing it using `pip`/`pip3`/`conda` which will all get the dependencies first? Or could you use `apt-get` to install the dependencies then try again, i.e. `sudo apt-get build-dep matplotlib`?

Comment: [Some meta problem](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Python 3.7 is in alpha status at the moment - are you sure you need that version? I haven't checked, but perhaps matplotlib (or one of its dependencies, which seems likely from your screenshot) has not yet been made compatible with 3.7. You might be happier with something like Anaconda: https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: I think the error tells you the solution. You would need to build freetype and png first.